# Embedding a native window in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I am trying to put a WinApi window into a Qt user interface for legacy reasons. It seems fairly straightforward:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(L"STATIC", L"Testwindow", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    QWidget *widget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(QWindow::fromWinId((WId)hwnd));
    ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(widget);
}
```

The WinApi window correctly appears inside the Qt window, however, resizing only works sometimes, leaving an ugly half resized window behind and I get this warning 4 times every second or so:

> QWindowsWindow::setGeometryDp: Unable to set geometry 366x366+20+285 on QWindow/''. Resulting geometry:  116x0+8+30 (frame: 0, 0, 0, 0, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 0x0, maximum size: 16777215x16777215).

It seems to be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494839/qt-adding-custom-widget-to-a-layout), which appearently has a solution which was never posted.

The resizing problem looks somewhat like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547131/qt-window-resize-problem), but I am using a layout hierarchy as suggested and the problem persists.

There seems to be an [alternative way to embed a native window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28786172/qt5-qwidgetcreate-with-win32-hwnd-embedding-not-longer-working-after-port-fr) using `QWidget::create(native_handle)`, but that one crashes on me.

How do I embed a native window in Qt so that it works correctly with resizing and has no `QWindowsWindow::setGeometryDp` issues?

Platform is Windows 7 with Qt 5.5.0 on VS 2013.

Comment: Could it be that you're not running an event loop for the native window?

Comment: @PBS: Qt dispatches native window messages already. When you're using a `QGuiApplication` you cannot not have a message loop.

Comment: @PBS Qt runs a native message loop and the `GetMessage` call has a `NULL` `hWnd`. Qt's event loop will dispatch all messages, to all windows running in a given thread. What you say would only apply if `Qt` called `GetMessage` with a non-null `hWnd`. Besides that quirk, it's not even possible to "run" an event loop for a certain native window only.

Comment: "It seems to be related to this" No, that's an unrelated issue.

Comment: It's a Qt bug. An answer would contain a workaround. It's supposed to work.

Comment: If you want to work with native windows, did you set AA_NativeWindows flag?

Comment: @Milovidov No, I suppose it goes to the `widget `? I will try that.

Comment: @Milovidov: The [AA_NativeWindows](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ApplicationAttribute-enum) flag *"ensures that widgets have native windows"*. It is used when you want all of your widgets to be backed by native windows. It has no effect, when you're creating a native window and create a widget container for it.

Comment: @IInspectable theoretically, yes. But in practice windows environment can change concrete window behaviour. Flag AA_NativeWindows change windows environment around window in container.

Comment: @Milovidov Setting `AA_NativeWindows` on the container widget causes a crash somewhere deep inside Qt. Guess I have to use `QOpenGLWidget` and port everything over.

Comment: @Milovidov: Are you suggesting, that the documentation is wrong? Or are you just promoting cargo-cult programming practices (*"Hey, this worked for me, although I don't know why. Give it a try!"*).

Comment: @IInspectable where I say, that documentation Is wrong? In documentation nothing about AA_NativeWindows flag in window container paragraph and this flag can really can affect to native win32 windows event looping, therefore can affect to native window, that integrated to QWidget.

Comment: @Milovidov: The windows event loop in Qt **never** accesses this particular application attribute. Consequently, it doesn't change message handling. Unless you have specific information, don't just sprout out guesstimates, that were poorly contrived.

Comment: @IInspectable man, just understand, if you will use this attribute, this will change event looping in Windows OS, because many windows will be created, and Qt application will handle these events, including resize events. This flag change environment for window in container and can affect to him bihaviour,

Comment: @Milovidov: You **cannot** change event looping in Windows, and Qt doesn't. It simply retrieves messages, and dispatches them. Like any Windows application does. The number of windows does not make the least bit of a difference. Whatever *"changes environment for window in container"* is supposed to mean, it's made up. Either provide specific information (which you cannot), or just let it rest (a viable option).

Comment: @IInspectable imagine two states - with once win32 window and with five win32 windows. Is win32 event loop will be different for these states?

Comment: @Milovidov: No. Both scenarios call `GetMessage` and `DispatchMessage`. The latter knows, where the message should go. Not the least bit of a difference. You don't seem to have answered a whole lot of [tag:winapi] questions, and it appears you don't have the background to really know, how a Windows application (and a Qt-application on Windows) works. You are just guessing along. This isn't very helpful.

Comment: @IInspectable the state machine of event looping of course not changing, but count of events and possible interwindows communication via windows events can be. This Is windows environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89923/discussion-between-iinspectable-and-milovidov).